# How to have version control on the files in FS using Products.Reflecto in Plone 4.1?

Tags: python, plone

I have added Products.Reflecto 2.5.1 in my Plone 4.1 on linux debian. Hence the files on the File system are directly accessible, But I cannot access these files for editing.For example Products.ImageEditor to edit the image on the FS in a reflector of my plone site. Nor can I edit the document files i.e description as in any other plone document upload. Also I cannot get the collective.quickupload portlet to allow multiple uploads. How can this be achieved. **Hence how does version control help for these uploaded files viz Reflecto files**. The history doesn't show any entries for the files modified outside Plone(thats but natural). How to use the version control with the uploaded files in Reflecto ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am one of the original authors of Reflecto.

From the [PyPi page for Reflecto](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.Reflecto):

> Reflecto is a tool to incorporate part of the file system into a Plone site. It allows you to browse through a filesystem hierarchy and access the files in it. Files are represented as simple downloadable object, not as full CMF or Plone content types.

So Reflecto is meant to show filesystem content inside a Plone website, but it clearly states that these files are not full Plone content types.

I'm not sure what requirements you have or exactly what you mean by version control; as a software developer I define that as [revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control), and because you are dealing with a full filesystem here I'd use a current revision control package such as SVN, git or mercurial for such a task. That of course does not integrate into Plone; Reflecto does not give you that level of integration.

As such it sounds like Reflecto is the wrong package for your problem. Perhaps you should look into importing your content into Plone to turn the files into full-blown content items?

Comment: Martijn Pieters Thank you for the clarificatio. By version control, I meant for the content in Plone just as the history option is readily available for the default content types in Plone :)

Comment: I guessed as much; we call it content history. To get full version control in Plone I'd generally use [iterate](http://plone.org/products/iterate).